# Is there a way to disable Quick Find in Visual Studio 2012?

Tags: visual-studio-2012

I just upgraded to Visual Studio 2012 from 2010 and cannot stand the fact that Cntrl + F brings up the new Quick Find dialog in the upper right hand corner of the editor. I typically just dock the Find and Replace window and prefer to use that. Is there a way to disable Cntrl + F from bringing up the new Quick Find window and instead have it move focus to the Find and Replace window similar to how VS 2010 did it?

Comment: This annoys me greatly.  But possibly for a different reason.  I do not like the fact that the current document jumps to the text as I'm typing it.  The reason being that I'm looking for a specific function in the current file and if its not there I'll do find in files search.  Well the quick find LOSES MY PLACE in the file while its randomly jumping through the file trying to find the search text!  Then I have the added step of going back to my place before running the find in files search.

Comment: I have a an i7-3930K cpu with 32 gigs of ram. I guess it's not powerful enough for quick find. It takes 1 or 2 seconds to pop up when I hit ctrl-f and about 1 second per keystroke to find text in files with more than a hundred or so lines of code. Nice idea. Bad implementation, I guess. Thanks for the question, I'm switching back to the older find.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes there is. You can assign the keyboard shortcut ctrl+f to edit.findinfiles in tools>options>environment>keyboard. So far it works for me.

Comment: Problem is, you have to manually change "Find what" to current document and change it back again when you really want to find in files.

Comment: Thank you! I was able to finally get it to work by updating the keyboard shortcuts like you said.

Comment: Also, the default button is `Find All`, so the result goes to the "Find Result Window", instead of selecting the text found. For that you'll have to click `Find Next` with the mouse:S There's not even a keyboard shortcut for it :(

Comment: Just made a AutoHotkey script to get around the above issues. Basically makes "Find in Files" dialog behave more like the good ol VS2010 Find dialog. See: http://pastebin.com/M0fVTzLr

Answer (score 3):

Instead of modifying the default keyboard shortcuts consider using

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> for "Find in files"

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd> for "Replace in files"

Sometimes it's not always possible/advisable to change the default shortcuts. Like when working on another persons computer.